# How do I slideDown whilst maintaining transparency in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm trying to animate a block level element using jQuery. The page loads with the element styled with `display: none`. Id like it to `slideDown` whilst transparent and then `fadeIn` the content using the callback, however `slideDown` appears to set the visibility to full before `fadeIn` is called, resulting in the content being visible during the `slideDown` animation.

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Could you explain whats the point of sliding down while transparent? The animation would not be seen, so why animate

Comment: I'm guessing he wants the vertical space to be taken before the element is shown

Comment: That's right - the space is made then the content appears

Comment: Did you try the solutions below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a few probable issues with your code: are you setting the content to hide as well in the beginning? are you calling `fadeIn` during the `slideDown` callback?

here's some example HTML/code that will `fadeIn` after the `slideDown`

```
$('div').hide(); // make sure you hide both container/content

$('#container').slideDown('slow', function() {
    $('#content').fadeIn('slow');    // fade in of content happens after slidedown
});
```

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">stuff</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using jQuery's .hide() rather than setting 'visibility' in CSS was the key. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$('#hiddenElement').css("opacity", 0).slideDown().animate({opacity:1})
```

Comment: I wonder why the downmod. As far as I can tell this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your description sounds like a variation of [this](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/2423) problem, which I had to deal with the other day.

It only happens in IE, and only if you are rendering in quirks mode. So the easy solution, is to switch to standards mode. You can find a table of doctypes [here](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/) that makes IE render in standards mode.

But if you are in the same situation as me where thats not an options, then you can apply a patch to you jQuery library, which you can find [here](http://dev.jquery.com/attachment/ticket/1726/1726.diff).

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add a `li` to a `ul` and wanted it to `slideDown` first, then `fadeIn`.

The below worked for me.  I had to first `.hide()` the content, then set opacity to 0, then append the content, then `slideDown()`, then animate the opacity back to 1.

In the below code, "content" is the `li`, #ListItems is the `ul`

```
$(content).hide().css("opacity", 0).appendTo("#ListItems").slideDown(500, function () { $(this).animate({ "opacity": 1 }, { queue: false, duration: 500 }); });
```